# This site can’t be reached The web page at express-basic-auth for swagger ui

Tags: express, nestjs, swagger-ui, basic-authentication, nestjs-swagger

I am trying to protect my swagger UI URL with express-basic-auth and it worked pretty fine locally in the nestjs server but when I uploaded it to my ubuntu vps it made accessing the swagger UI page not possible and chrome is showing this error

```
This site can’t be reachedThe web page at http://mydomain/docs might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_TOO_MANY_RETRIES
```

Here is how I implemented it

```
  app.use(
    '/docs*',
    expressBasicAuth({
      challenge: true,
      users: {
        user: 'password',
      },
    }),
  );
```

Comment: try it in **incognito** window . and see if it give you the same error

Comment: I added more detail in the answer below you can check it , this error is coming from chrome  in your case I guess you are getting this error because one of the extensions in your  browser is blocking the site , or you have to clear cache  in chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, Chrome uses this error message  `This site can’t be reached The web page at HTTP:.. might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.` As a catch-all description for a lot of errors, it indicates that Chrome is unable to establish a connection to the website you're trying to access.

**these are some steps to fix this error :**

**1 -** Check Internet Connection .

**2 -** `try it on incognito` window if it works then go back to your Chrome and  *Clear Browser Cache* (Sometimes, cached data in your browser can cause issues with accessing websites) and *disable all extensions*

**3 -** Change Your DNS Servers

**4 -** Disable your firewall and antivirus.